# Error While reading PDF file using IText c#

Tags: c#, parsing, itext

I am reading pdf file using iTextSharp.text.pdf.
But as you can see in the code below when I am trying to read first page of the pdf it is giving me **error message** : "**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**"

But it is not giving error message when I am reading 2nd or third page.

Below is the code I am using to read PDF File.

```
StringBuilder pdfContent = new StringBuilder();
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
int pageCount = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
       ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i, strategy);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            pdfContent.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text))));
        }

        if (parser != null)
        {
            parser.ProcessContent(i, imageRenderListener);
        }
    }
pdfReader.Close();

return pdfContent.ToString();
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: This sounds like an error in the PDF that is being tolerated by PDF viewers. Please share the PDF. Also: please use the latest version of iText (iTextSharp isn't the latest version since we abandoned the name iTextSharp two years ago). The latest version is iText 7 for .NET: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET

Comment: Removing "ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();" from my code worked for my. I don't know how. Can I put it as an answer?

Comment: Have you replaced `strategy` with `null` in the `GetTextFromPage()` method? If not, I don't believe your solution works, because you have a variable `strategy` this is no longer defined if you remove that line.

Comment: I removed it, where ever it was used

Comment: OK, then you can post that as your answer, although it's not a satisfying answer. It doesn't explain why the *"Index was outside the bounds of the array."* occurs, and we didn't get sufficient information to see if we can change something in iText to avoid this error in the future. In short: while that answer might be useful for you, it's not useful for anyone else.